# Data shows when page accessed from internally, but not on public site

Tags: salesforce

I have been following the salesforce Recruiting App tutorial, and reached the section on creating a public site:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_composite_app_public_sites.htm

I have built a simple page to display open jobs as described here:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_composite_app_create_public_jobs_try_it_out.htm

This is displaying the open jobs correctly when I view it through our "internal" URL: https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/PublicJobs

But when I view this same page through our "external" URL: http://servian-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/careers, the page still renders, except that now the list of jobs is empty.

I don't think this is a permissions error, as if so it would surely prompt me to log in.  What do I need to do to make the data show on the "external" URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the "guest" user for the site has Read permission for the Positions object on its profile. You can't access the profile for the guest user through the normal Profile list page in Setup; instead, click on the Public Access Settings button from your site's detail page. On the profile, go all the way to the bottom of the page and make sure the Read permission is checked. If its still not working, ensure the Field Level Security settings also correct for that profile. The FLS settings are controlled about mid-way down on the same page.

Comment: OK thanks for that - the Field Level Security was not set correctly.  Now I have enabled access for the three fields the page is trying to display, I can see NEW Position records that I create.  However, on the public URL, I still don't see records that were created before I enabled it (ie. historically).  On the private URL, I still see all records.  What can be causing this?

Comment: Do you have caching enabled on the Visualforce page? Pages served through Sites get cached by a CDN, so you might have been seeing the version of the page from before the FLS change you made. Check the page again now and see if its reflecting the change.

Comment: Nope, it still only shows those two jobs I created, whereas the private URL is showing all of them. ???

Comment: Ok, now I'm thinking it is something with record ownership and sharing. Can you go to Setup | Security Controls | Sharing Settings, and check what the "Default Access" is set to for Positions? If it is Private, it would mean that the records created internally (as an admin user) are not visible to the external url (as the guest user), not because of the URL itself, but because the admin user owns the records and are not shared with the guest user. If that is the case, try changing it to "Public Read/Write", which will open up sharing to all users.

Comment: I don't really understand this.  Today, without knowingly making any changes, all the records are now showing correctly.  Confused.  For the record, the Default Access for Position records was set to Public Read Only.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm...I'm going back to my caching theory then. Can you check in your Visualforce page that you don't have anything like this: `<apex:page cache="true">`

Comment: Actually, I just looked at the doc closer, and realized it defaults to true for Sites, so make sure you explicitly put `<apex:page cache="false">` in your page. Here's the doc on it: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_page.htm

Comment: Thanks - in future if I get this problem again I will try that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, ensure the object, if it is a custom object is in "Deployed" status. This fixed the issue for us.

Additional Information (from help.salesforce.com):

While developing a custom object or external object, you might not want users to see and interact with it. Because users might get frustrated with changes in layout or lose data when you delete custom fields, control visibility of the new object until you are finished.
Use the Deployment Status setting in the object definition to control when users can see and use the object and its associated custom tab, related lists, and reports.
Choose “In Development” as the Deployment Status when first creating your custom object or external object. Doing so hides it from users while you are designing and testing it. Only users with the “Customize Application” permission can see the object tab, search results, related lists, and report data types.
Change the Deployment Status to “Deployed” when you want to allow all users to use the object and any associated custom tab, related lists, and reports.
If you make more enhancements after deploying a custom object or external object, you can change the Deployment Status back to “In Development.”